# Solve Non-homogeneous recurrence relations

Tags: recurrence-relations

Solve the recurrence relation $u_n = 2u_{n-1} + 2^n - 1$ where n is greater than or equal to 1 and $u_0=0$.

We have characteristic root equal to 2 with multiplicity 1. So homogeneous part will have solution $A.2^n$, where A is constant. 
The particular solution should be of the form $P.n.2^n + Q$, where P, Q are constants. Now when I put this in original recurrence I can't solve. Plz help.

Comment: i think it is this here $$u(n)\to c_1 2^{n-1}+2^n \left(n+2^{-n}-1\right)$$

Comment: Didn't understand. The form of particular solution that I assumed here is right or not?

Comment: set this in your recurrence relation

Comment: I did that. But could not solve.

Comment: You have the right form for the particular solution. Show us what happens when you try to use it to get $P$ and $Q$.

Comment: I get following when I put in the recurrence $ u_n = 2*u_{n-1 } + 2^n - 1 $. =>  $P*n*2^n+Q = 2[P(n-1)*2^{n-1} +Q] + 2^n-1$

Comment: $P*n*2^n = P*n*2^n - P*2^n + 2^n + 2Q - q $

Comment: Now how should I proceed.

Answer (score 2):

HINT: Multiply out the righthand side:

$$\begin{align*}
Pn2^n+Q&=2P(n-1)2^{n-1}+2Q+2^n-1\\
&=P(n-1)2^n+2Q+2^n-1\\
&=Pn2^n-(P-1)2^n+2Q-1
\end{align*}$$

Subtract $Pn2^n+Q$ from both sides and rearrange a little:

$$Q-1=(P-1)2^n$$

This has to hold for **all** $n\ge 0$, so what must $P$ be? And what does that force $Q$ to be?

Comment: There can be many values for P and Q. How can I get the values if the equation has three unknowns P, Q and n?

Comment: $n$ is **not** an unknown – as Brian writes, this is meant to be an identity that holds for **all** values of $n$.

Comment: @user5267640: If you don't see why the fact that it holds for **all** $n$ forces $P$ to have a certain value, you can use a slightly more brute force approach. It holds for $n=0$, so $Q-1=P-1$. It also holds for $n=1$; that gives you another equation in $P$ and $Q$; solve that pair of equations for $P$ and $Q$.

Comment: It means I can take two values of n arbitrarily and find two equations in P and Q. When I did this for n= 0, 1 I got P = Q =1. Am I right?

Comment: Do you have to ask?

Comment: @user5267640: Yes, that’s correct. Note that this can be seen without actually going to all that trouble. The value of $2^n$ changes as $n$ changes, so if $P-1\ne 0$, $(P-1)2^n$ is not a constant. Clearly $Q-1$ *is* a constant, so the only way the two can be equal for all $n$ is for $P-1$ to be $0$, i.e., for $P$ to be $1$. In that case $(P-1)2^n$ is always $0$, so $Q-1$ has to be $0$ as well, and therefore $Q=1$.

Comment: Yeah. I got that. Thanks everyone for the valuable advice.